# "far"="fare de", "per"="pere de", ĉu oni povus apliki ĉi tiun regulon al aliaj vortoj?

Tags: grammar

*far*="fare de", *per*="pere de", do ĉu oni povus apliki ĉi tiun regulon al aliaj vortoj. Ekz. *dir* = "dire de", aŭ eĉ *leg* = "lege de", *la libro leg mi estas bona*., *la vortoj dir li estas malĝustaj*.

Answer (score 9):

La regulo estas: Oni povas fari E-vorton el rolvorteto (prepozicio), per -> pere, en -> ene, kun -> kune k.t.p.

Sed ne eblas krei rolvorteton el E-vorto (el ordinara radiko).
￼
La rolvorteto "far" estas neregula kreaĵo. Ne uzu ĝin. Ĝi estas neregula kaj (plej grave) nebezonata.

Comment: Terure se oni emas mencii PMEGon kaj Bertilo mem ĉeestas... tamen mi almenaŭ aŭdacas enmeti ligilon ... Homoj, demandinto, legu pri [far en PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neoficialaj_vortetoj.html#i-z97)

Answer (score 4):

La radiko *per* estas prepozicio, kies baza uzo estas sen finaĵo. Aldone eblas adverbigi la prepozicion al *pere*, kaj uzi ĝin en la esprimo *pere de*, kies signifo tamen ne estas identa al la signifo de *per* (tion bone klarigas Andrew Woods en sia respondo). Ĝenerale oni povas tiel adverbigi prepozicion. Kutimaj ekzemploj estas *kune*, *kontraŭe*, *ene* kaj *dume*.

La radiko *far* estas verba radiko, kies baza uzo estas kun verba finaĵo (*fari*, *faras*, *faris* ktp). Krome, oni povas anstataŭigi la verban finaĵon per substantiva finaĵo (*faro*) aŭ adjektiva sfinaĵo (*fara*, kiu tamen estas tre malofta), kio modifas kaj la signifon kaj la gramatikan funkcion de la vorto. Radikoj, kies baza uzo estas kun finaĵo, ĝenerale ne povas esti uzataj sen finaĵo. Do la uzo de *far* sen finaĵo en la funkcio de prepozicio ne baziĝas sur normala vortfara regulo. Pro tio oni prefere evitu ĝin, kaj uzu anstataŭe *de* aŭ *fare de* (la pli longa *fare de* ĉefe utilas, kiam temas pri kunteksto, en kiu *de* ne estas sufiĉe klara).

Answer (score 3):

Ne, ne ekzistas ia regulo de tiu speco. Kiam vorto aŭdiĝas sen taŭga finaĵo, preskaŭ ĉiam oni devus supozi ke la preterlasita finaĵo estus *-o*.

La malofta vorto *far* estas esence mallongigo de *fare de*. Oni uzas *fare de* por distingi du samtempajn uzojn de la vorto *de*. Ekzemple: *Mi legis la biografion de Browning far(e de) Chesterton.*

La esprimo *pere de* ne egalas *per* precize. *Pere de* aludas al pera (interhelpa) aĵo.

- Se oni uzas ĉefe unu ilon por fari ion, oni *faras per la ilo*. Ekzemple: *Mi malfermis la paketon per tondilo.*
- Se oni faras ion kun helpo de ilo, oni *faras pere de la ilo.* Ekzemple: *Mi legis ĝin pere de esperanta traduko. Mi sendis la leteron pere de amiko.*

En normala Esperanto, viaj ekzemploj estus tiel: *La libro kiun mi legas/legis estas bona. La libro legata/legita de mi estas bona.* Simile: *la vortoj kiujn 
vi diris* aŭ *la vortoj diritaj de vi* aŭ simple *viaj vortoj*...

Answer (score 1):

> ...ĉu oni povus apliki ĉi tiun regulon al aliaj vortoj?

Mi pensas, ke ne, ĉar la vorto **far** ne estas oficiala prepozicio. Oni diru nur "fare de".

> Note that, although far has become relatively common, the Academy of Esperanto, like many Esperantists, (rightly) objects to it because it is irregular to use a verbal stem as a preposition. http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq190.html

**Tradukon:** Notu, ke kvankam nun la vorto fariĝis relative komuna, la Akademio de Esperanto, kaj multaj esperantistoj, (prave) kontestas, ĉar estas malregula uzi parola tigo kiel prepozicio.

Answer (score 0):

La unua problemo estas ke “per” ne egalas “pere de”.

Pri "far" - tio estas propono aŭ slangaĵo.

Pri "dire de" kaj "lege de" - mi dubas ĉu ili estas bonaj esprimoj. "Fare" precizigas la signifon de "de" - kiu jam inluzivas la signifon "fare de". "De" ne inkuzivas la signifon "dire de" aŭ "lege de" (eventuale "dirita de" kaj "legita de" ĉu ne?), do sekve ne eblas precizigi al tiu signifo.